# Get rid of the disrupting points

Tags: deep-learning, unsupervised-learning, scatterplot

Here on the following picture, we can identify two clouds. We can identify a lot of points that are out of the two clouds and can disrupt a bit the the training and test accuracy (%). Is there an unsupervised machine learning model or other techniques we can use to get rid of those points?

I thought to try to train a neural network to maximize inter class distances, but minimize intra class distances, but it is a bit unclear.

[image]

To explain the image here, I have over 76 features I pass to a LSTM model. The graph axis you see are the three first principal components (i.e. related to PCA). The red dots are -1 labels and blue dots are the 1 labels.

Comment: Why would you get rid of those points? So that the model performance looks better than it actually is?

Comment: Yes, this is the main purpose. I have a LSTM model that process the labels, and I am pretty sure the performance will be inscreased if we remove the disrupting points.

Comment: Ok, I can propose you a simple but inefficient algorithm: remove points from set one by one checking if the performance improved after removal.

Comment: Ok, figure the graph you see here is a single day. Image I have to remove the disrupted points for ten years of data. It should be exhausting very quickly.

Comment: @Jeremie You're missing the subtext of Aksakal's messages.  If those are real datapoints, you want to find a methodology that respects them, instead of using a methodology that does not, and pretending they do not exist.  Dropping data to increase model performance is not a good idea.  If you want to drop the data, you will need to support that decision in another way.